# Export generated functions in package

Tags: r, package

I often find myself having to handle vectors which may or may not be full of `NA` values. These `NAs` are expected and should be discarded, which is usually handled by most functions by an `na.rm = TRUE` argument.

However, sometimes the vectors will be entirely `NA`, which causes many functions to misbehave:

```
min(NA, na.rm = TRUE)
#> Warning in min(NA, na.rm = TRUE): no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
#> [1] Inf
```

So I frequently have to handle this case separately.

However, I have a personal utilities package and it occurred to me that I can handle this quite easily with a wrapper function.

```
min.na <- function(..., .ifEmpty = NA) {
  x <- na.omit(c(...))

  if(length(x) == 0) return(.ifEmpty)
  else return(min(x))
}

min.na(NA)
#> [1] NA
```

But `min` obviously isn't the only function with this sort of behavior (if nothing else, `max` does the same thing, obviously).

So I thought it best to create a generator function `.FUN.na` which handles all the functions equally, and derive `min.na` and `max.na` from it:

```
.FUN.na <- function(FUN, ..ifEmpty = NA) {
  return(
    function(..., .ifEmpty = ..ifEmpty) {
      x <- na.omit(c(...))

      if(length(x) == 0) return(.ifEmpty)
      else return(FUN(x))
    }
  )
}

#' @export
min.na <- .FUN.na(min)

#' @export
max.na <- .FUN.na(max)
```

However, when I update the NAMESPACE file and rebuild the package, the functions aren't exported. They are added to the package and work, but can only be accessed via the triple-colon `foo:::min.na()`.

How can I make these publicly exported?

Comment: You could use `max_` and `min_` from `hablar` `hablar::min_(NA)#
[1] NA`

Comment: @akrun one day I'll know more than 1% of the R packages out there... thanks for the encyclopedic knowledge. Checking `hablar` docs now.